# Replace invalid values with None in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, nan

Is there any method to replace values with `None` in Pandas in Python?

You can use `df.replace('pre', 'post')` and can replace a value with another, but this can't be done if you want to replace with `None` value, which if you try, you get a strange result.

So here's an example:

```
df = DataFrame(['-',3,2,5,1,-5,-1,'-',9])
df.replace('-', 0)
```

which returns a successful result.

But,

```
df.replace('-', None)
```

which returns a following result:

```
0
0   - // this isn't replaced
1   3
2   2
3   5
4   1
5  -5
6  -1
7  -1 // this is changed to `-1`...
8   9
```

Why does such a strange result be returned?

Since I want to pour this data frame into MySQL database, I can't put `NaN` values into any element in my data frame and instead want to put `None`. Surely, you can first change `'-'` to `NaN` and then convert `NaN` to `None`, but I want to know why the dataframe acts in such a terrible way.

> Tested on pandas 0.12.0 dev on Python 2.7 and OS X 10.8. Python is a
>   pre-installed version on OS X and I installed pandas by using SciPy
>   Superpack script, for your information.

Comment: Does the `write_frame` not parse `NaN`s to `none`s?

Comment: Yup. You encounter `InternalError: (1054, u"Unknown column 'nan' in 'field list'")` error. I don't know about any solutions on it other than converting `NaN` to `None` before executing `write_frame` method.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Scipy super pack gives out dev? Ok, well I definitely think you should [raise this as an issue on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues), shouldn't be too hard to fix.

Comment: **If you are reading this data from CSV/Excel**, you can read these values in as NaN using `na_values` argument. [More information in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55469393/4909087)

Comment: In case anyone is here primarily due to the second questionable part of the replace (where a value of `-1` is introduced on record 7), this is due to a default value of `'pad'` as the `method` parameter.  If a maintainer of pandas happens to be reading this, that default behavior is _NOT_ desirable in virtually any environment I've experienced and easily results in data corruption!

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Actually in later versions of pandas this will give a TypeError:

```
df.replace('-', None)
TypeError: If "to_replace" and "value" are both None then regex must be a mapping
```

You can do it by passing either a list or a dictionary:

```
In [11]: df.replace('-', df.replace(['-'], [None]) # or .replace('-', {0: None})
Out[11]:
      0
0  None
1     3
2     2
3     5
4     1
5    -5
6    -1
7  None
8     9
```

But I recommend using NaNs rather than None:

```
In [12]: df.replace('-', np.nan)
Out[12]:
     0
0  NaN
1    3
2    2
3    5
4    1
5   -5
6   -1
7  NaN
8    9
```

Comment: Or simply a list, e.g. `df.replace(['-'], [None])`, or `df.replace({'-': None})`, I think.  The use of `None` as a sentinel precludes using it as a value too..

Comment: @user2360798 replace is actually a very feature-rich (read complicated) function, the [(dev)docstring](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) is really good though.

Comment: I don't know if it's obvious, but had to assign `df` back to itself like: `df = df.replace({'?': np.nan})`

Comment: @AndyHayden `df.replace('-', df.replace(['-'], [None])` looks funky, is that a typo?

Comment: @lin_bug I think should just be df.replace(['-'], [None]) :) good catch!

Comment: @lin_bug Though it seems the no longer works in recent pandas versions. df.where(df!='-', None) works

Comment: I don't know which version of pandas would return that error. I have pandas 0.23.4, and there was no TypeError for me. pandas displayeds the behavior explained by @Blaszard: the vlue is copied from the row before instead of being set to None

Comment: @raffamaiden `df.where(df!='-', None)` seems to work, perhaps the only one to work. Yes, this answer is rather old (nearly 6 years! I guess that deprecation/warning/TypeError was removed), definitely agree with cs95 that it should be parsed during read_csv.

Comment: @AndyHayden I agree with him to, but still, is it strange behavior of assigning the value of the previous row to None documented somewhere or is it a bug?

Comment: @raffamaiden it may be worth creating an issue, the problem is that None in python is used for all optional arguments so pandas can't tell whether it's .replace(x) vs .replace(x, None)... that said this is strange behavior either way

Answer (score 36):

I prefer the solution using [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas-dataframe-replace) with a `dict` because of its simplicity and elegance:

```
df.replace({'-': None})
```

You can also have more replacements:

```
df.replace({'-': None, 'None': None})
```

And even for larger replacements, it is always obvious and clear what is replaced by what - which is way harder for long lists, in my opinion.

Comment: It is worth noting that part of why this technique works is that usage of the `dict` type in `to_replace` causes the `method` parameter to not be evaluated, and thus the `method='pad'` default to have no ill effects.

Answer (score 18):

`where` is probably what you're looking for. So

```
data=data.where(data=='-', None)
```

From the [panda docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

> `where` [returns] an object of same shape as self and whose corresponding entries are from self where cond is True and otherwise are from other).

Comment: This is actually inaccurate.  data=data.where(data=='-', None) will replace anything that is NOT EQUAL to '-' with None.  Pandas version of where keeps the value of the first arg(in this case data=='-'), and replace anything else with the second arg (in this case None).  It is a bit confusing as np.where is more explicit in that it asks the conditional in the first arg, then the if true in the second arg, then the if false in the 3rd arg.

Answer (score 14):

Before proceeding with this post, **it is important to understand [the difference between NaN and None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534106/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-none)**. One is a float type, the other is an object type. Pandas is better suited to working with scalar types as many methods on these types can be vectorised. Pandas does try to handle None and NaN consistently, but NumPy cannot.

My suggestion ([and Andy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17097397/4909087)) is to stick with NaN.

But to answer your question...

#### pandas >= 0.18: Use `na_values=['-']` argument with `read_csv`

If you loaded this data from CSV/Excel, I have good news for you. You can quash this at the root during data loading instead of having to write a fix with code as a subsequent step.

Most of the `pd.read_*` functions (such as [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)) accept a **`na_values`** attribute.

`file.csv`

```
A,B
-,1
3,-
2,-
5,3
1,-2
-5,4
-1,-1
-,0
9,0
```

Now, to convert the `-` characters into NaNs, do,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', na_values=['-'])
df

     A    B
0  NaN  1.0
1  3.0  NaN
2  2.0  NaN
3  5.0  3.0
4  1.0 -2.0
5 -5.0  4.0
6 -1.0 -1.0
7  NaN  0.0
8  9.0  0.0
```

And similar for other functions/file formats.

P.S.: On v0.24+, you can preserve integer type even if your column has NaNs (yes, talk about having the cake and eating it too). You can specify `dtype='Int32'`

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', na_values=['-'], dtype='Int32')
df

     A    B
0  NaN    1
1    3  NaN
2    2  NaN
3    5    3
4    1   -2
5   -5    4
6   -1   -1
7  NaN    0
8    9    0

df.dtypes

A    Int32
B    Int32
dtype: object
```

The dtype is not a conventional int type... but rather, a [Nullable Integer Type.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html#nullable-integer-data-type) There are other options.

---

## Handling Numeric Data: `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce`

If you're dealing with numeric data, a faster solution is to use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with the `errors='coerce'` argument, which coerces invalid values (values that cannot be cast to numeric) to NaN.

```
pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce')

0    NaN
1    3.0
2    2.0
3    5.0
4    1.0
5   -5.0
6   -1.0
7    NaN
8    9.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

To retain (nullable) integer dtype, use

```
pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce').astype('Int32')

0    NaN
1      3
2      2
3      5
4      1
5     -5
6     -1
7    NaN
8      9
Name: A, dtype: Int32
```

To coerce multiple columns, use `apply`:

```
df[['A', 'B']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').astype('Int32')

     A    B
0  NaN    1
1    3  NaN
2    2  NaN
3    5    3
4    1   -2
5   -5    4
6   -1   -1
7  NaN    0
8    9    0
```

...and assign the result back after.

More information can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47942854).

Answer (score 8):

With Pandas version ≥1.0.0, I would use [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) or [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df.replace(old_val, pd.NA, inplace=True)
```

This is better for two reasons:

1. It uses [**`pd.NA`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#experimental-na-scalar-to-denote-missing-values) instead of `None` or `np.nan`.
2. It optionally works *in-place* which could be more memory efficient depending upon the internal implementation.

Answer (score 3):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['-',3,2,5,1,-5,-1,'-',9])
df = df.where(df!='-', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting null values can be done with `np.nan`:

```
import numpy as np
df.replace('-', np.nan)
```

Advantage is that `df.last_valid_index()` recognizes these as invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Using replace and assigning a new df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['-',3,2,5,1,-5,-1,'-',9])
dfnew = df.replace('-', 0)
print(dfnew)


(venv) D:\assets>py teste2.py
   0
0  0
1  3
2  2
3  5
4  1
5 -5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.replace('-', np.nan).astype("object")
```

This will ensure that you can use `isnull()` later on your dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df.mask(df=='-', None)
```