# What is the difference between NaN and None?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, nan

I am reading two columns of a csv file using pandas `readcsv()` and then assigning the values to a dictionary. The columns contain strings of numbers and letters. Occasionally there are cases where a cell is empty. In my opinion, the value read to that dictionary entry should be `None` but instead `nan` is assigned. Surely `None` is more descriptive of an empty cell as it has a null value, whereas `nan` just says that the value read is not a number.

Is my understanding correct, what IS the difference between `None` and `nan`? Why is `nan` assigned instead of `None`?

Also, my dictionary check for any empty cells has been using `numpy.isnan()`:

```
for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
    if np.isnan(v):
```

But this gives me an error saying that I cannot use this check for `v`. I guess it is because an integer or float variable, not a string is meant to be used. If this is true, how can I check `v` for an "empty cell"/`nan` case?

Comment: The text `qwerty` is not a number.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I know, so surely `None` would be a better description of the value of an empty cell.

Comment: Linked: [Why numpy.nan is different than math.nan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68256057/why-numpy-nan-is-different-than-math-nan)

Answer (score 173, accepted):

NaN is used as a placeholder for [missing data *consistently* in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/gotchas.html#choice-of-na-representation), consistency is good. I usually read/translate NaN as **"missing"**. *Also see the ['working with missing data'](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html) section in the docs.*

Wes writes in the docs ['choice of NA-representation'](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/gotchas.html#choice-of-na-representation):

> After years of production use [NaN] has proven, at least in my opinion, to be the best decision given the state of affairs in NumPy and Python in general. The special value NaN (Not-A-Number) is used *everywhere* as the NA value, and there are API functions [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html#pandas.DataFrame.isna) and [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html#pandas.DataFrame.notna) which can be used across the dtypes to detect NA values.
> ...
> Thus, I have chosen the Pythonic “practicality beats purity” approach and traded integer NA capability for a much simpler approach of using a special value in float and object arrays to denote NA, and promoting integer arrays to floating when NAs must be introduced.

*Note: the ["gotcha" that integer Series containing missing data are upcast to floats](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na).*

In my opinion the main reason to use NaN (over None) is that it can be stored with numpy's float64 dtype, rather than the less efficient object dtype, *see [NA type promotions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/gotchas.html#na-type-promotions)*.

```
#  without forcing dtype it changes None to NaN!
s_bad = pd.Series([1, None], dtype=object)
s_good = pd.Series([1, np.nan])

In [13]: s_bad.dtype
Out[13]: dtype('O')

In [14]: s_good.dtype
Out[14]: dtype('float64')
```

Jeff comments (below) on this:

> `np.nan` allows for vectorized operations; its a float value, while `None`, by definition, forces object type, which basically disables all efficiency in numpy.
>
> > **So repeat 3 times fast: object==bad, float==good**

Saying that, many operations may still work just as well with None vs NaN (but perhaps are not supported i.e. they may sometimes give [surprising results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19866269/1240268)):

```
In [15]: s_bad.sum()
Out[15]: 1

In [16]: s_good.sum()
Out[16]: 1.0
```

---

To answer the second question:
You should be using [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html#pandas.DataFrame.isna) and [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html#pandas.DataFrame.notna) to test for missing data (NaN).

Comment: just adding 2c here....``np.nan`` allows for vectorized operations; its a float value, while ``None`` by definition forces ``object`` type, and basically disables all efficiency in numpy, so repeat 3 times fast: ``object==bad, float==good``

Comment: Is `<NA>` also an `np.nan`?

Comment: The question was specifically about pandas. This answer is great, why isn't it presented first?!

Comment: another gotcha for this case:
`bool(None) -> False`, while `bool(float('nan')) -> True)`

Answer (score 34):

`NaN` can be used as a numerical value on mathematical operations, while `None` cannot (or at least shouldn't).

`NaN` is a numeric value, as defined in [IEEE 754 floating-point standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).
`None` is an internal Python type (`NoneType`) and would be more like "inexistent" or "empty" than "numerically invalid" in this context.

The main "symptom" of that is that, if you perform, say, an average or a sum on an array containing NaN, even a single one, you get NaN as a result...

In the other hand, you cannot perform mathematical operations using `None` as operand.

So, depending on the case, you could use `None` as a way to tell your algorithm not to consider invalid or inexistent values on computations. That would mean the algorithm should test each value to see if it is `None`.

Numpy has some functions to avoid NaN values to contaminate your results, such as `nansum` and `nan_to_num` for example.

Comment: I agree with you that None should be used for non-existent entries, so why does `df=pd.readcsv('file.csv')` give me `NaN` values for the empty cells and not `None`? As far as I'm aware, pd.DataFrames are not exclusive for numbers.

Comment: Well, it's probably a design choice. I suppose DataFrames and Series have a `dtype`, so invalid values of `dtype=float` must be represented by numeric values, which `NaN` is and `None` is not (`None` is of `NoneType`).

Comment: Also, a lot of Pandas methods have a `na` argument, which let you decide which value you are going to use to replace not-available values

Comment: Ok, thanks. So I am not actually reading numbers into my DataFrame, but strings of numbers and letters. What sort of check should I be using to detect empty cells? A check like; if dtype==float: ??

Comment: Perhaps posting a sample of your CSV data would help. I can imagine that, if there are strings, then dtype would be string for the whole column (Series). But perhaps if not every row has the same number of columns, you end up with unavailable data. I think you'll have to check that.

Comment: Maybe this would help http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.dtype.html

Comment: @heltonbiker pandas chooses object as the dtype for columns with strings (see note [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#attributes-and-the-raw-ndarray-s)). Otherwise it has to store the size of the largest element for every element (usually you don't know every string is a specific/the same length).

Comment: Could you provide a code example for "if you perform, say, an average or a sum on an array containing NaN, even a single one, you get NaN as a result"? For me `pd.__version__ == '0.23.4'; pd.Series([1,2,np.NaN]).mean() == 1.5`

Comment: @heltonbiker yeah you are right read_csv() gives NaN but when you read excel and xlsb file It will give you None.

Answer (score 3):

The function [`isnan()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.isnan) checks to see if something is "Not A Number" and will return whether or not a variable is a number, for example `isnan(2)` would return false

The conditional `myVar is not None` returns whether or not the variable is defined

Your numpy array uses `isnan()` because it is intended to be an array of numbers and it initializes all elements of the array to `NaN` these elements are considered "empty"

Comment: I think `isnan(2)` would return `False`, since 2 is not a NaN.

Comment: Also, `numpy.empty` doesn't initialize array values to `NaN`. It simply doesn't initialize the values at all.

Comment: The proper check for `None`-ness is `myVar is not None`, not `myVar != None`.

Comment: Note that `np.isnan()` is not implemented for string variables, so if you pass it a string it will crash. Better to use `pd.isnull` which works with strings.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the differences:

- `nan` belongs to the class `float`
- `None` belongs to the class `NoneType`

I found the below article very helpful:
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/dealing-with-missing-values-nan-and-none-in-python-6fc9b8fb4f31