# Overwriting (updating) a pandas Series with values from another Series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas Series: `ser` and `ovr`.

`ser` contains objects, and `ovr` is a sparse `Series` of objects and `None`'s. `ser` and `ovr` share the same index, and I'd like to overwrite every value of `ser` with its corresponding value of `ovr`, unless that corresponding value is `None`.

What's an efficient way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[I recommend using NaN for missing data rather than None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534106/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-none/17534682#17534682) (Note: this technique also works with None).

```
In [1]: s1 = pd.Series([1, np.nan, 3, 4, 5, np.nan])

In [2]: s2 = pd.Series([7, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan])
```

First see that s2 values which are not NaN (or None), these are those which you want to update s1 with:

```
In [3]: s2[s2.notnull()]
Out[3]:
0    7
1    2
2    3
dtype: float64
```

And then you can update the values of s1 with these:

```
In [4]: s1.update(s2[s2.notnull()])

In [5]: s1
Out[5]:
0     7
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     5
5   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works well. BTW, why do you recommend NaN over None for missing values, even when the `Series` in question is of dtype `object`?

Comment: @DunPeal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534106/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-none/17534682#17534682

Comment: @AndyHayden I really needed the answer to this question but couldn't find it for ages on Google. Can we edit the question to get rid of the sparse stuff which isn't really relevant and change "override" in the title to "replace" or "update"?

Comment: The title's much better now!

Comment: It's actually even easier than this. You don't need to get rid of the nulls in `s2`. Simply `s1.update(s2)` will work. See [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html): '*If other contains NaNs the corresponding values are not updated in the original Series.*' (Perhaps this API has changed in the last 7 years!)