# python: convert numerical data in pandas dataframe to floats in the presence of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a pandas dataframe with a column 'cap'. This column mostly consists of floats but has a few strings in it, for instance at index 2.

```
df =
    cap
0    5.2
1    na
2    2.2
3    7.6
4    7.5
5    3.0
...
```

I import my data from a csv file like so:

```
df = DataFrame(pd.read_csv(myfile.file))
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, the column 'cap' is imported entirely as strings. I would like floats to be identified as floats and strings as strings. Trying to convert this using:

```
df['cap'] = df['cap'].astype(float)
```

throws up an error:

```
could not convert string to float: na
```

Is there any way to make all the numbers into floats but keep the 'na' as a string?

Comment: I think this might be hurtful for performance. Mixed types in a column force you `dtype=object` while you might get along with `dtype=float`. There's a special "not a number" float value (`numpy.nan`) that is good for indicating missing data. Also [Pandas understands it very well.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html)

Comment: you just need to specify ``na_values=['na']`` in the ``read_csv`` and it will work, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#na-values)

Comment: alternatively you can use ``df.convert_objects(convert_numeric='force')`` to force non-numeric to ``nan`` (implemented in cython so its very fast)

Comment: You consider accepting this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19866269/2087463).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible workaround

first you define a function that converts numbers to float only when needed

```
 def to_number(s):
    try:
        s1 = float(s)
        return s1
    except ValueError:
        return s
```

and then you apply it row by row.

---

**Example:**

given

```
 df 
     0
  0  a
  1  2
```

where both `a` and `2` are strings, we do the conversion via

```
converted = df.apply(lambda f : to_number(f[0]) , axis = 1)  

 converted
 0    a
 1    2
```

A direct check on the types:

```
type(converted.iloc[0])                                                                                                                             
str

type(converted.iloc[1])                                                                                                                             
float
```

Comment: Although this works to do what the OP asks, doing it is not really useful imo since you can't do any analysis...

Comment: @AndyHayden, I do agree..Thanks for posting your solution

Answer (score 21):

*Calculations with columns of float64 dtype (rather than object) are much more efficient, so this is usually preferred... it will also allow you to do other calculations. Because of this is [recommended to use NaN for missing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534106/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-none/17534682#17534682) (rather than your own placeholder, or None).*

#### Is this really the answer you want?

```
In [11]: df.sum()  # all strings
Out[11]: 
cap    5.2na2.27.67.53.0
dtype: object

In [12]: df.apply(lambda f: to_number(f[0]), axis=1).sum()  # floats and 'na' strings
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

You should use convert_numeric to coerce to floats:

```
In [21]: df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[21]: 
   cap
0  5.2
1  NaN
2  2.2
3  7.6
4  7.5
5  3.0
```

Or read it in directly as a csv, by appending 'na' to the list of values to be considered NaN:

```
In [22]: pd.read_csv(myfile.file, na_values=['na'])
Out[22]: 
   cap
0  5.2
1  NaN
2  2.2
3  7.6
4  7.5
5  3.0
```

In either case, sum (and many other pandas functions) will now work:

```
In [23]: df.sum()
Out[23]:
cap    25.5
dtype: float64
```

As [Jeff advises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534106/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-none/17534682#comment25507184_17534682):

> #### repeat 3 times fast: object==bad, float==good

Answer (score 2):

First of all the way you import you CSV is redundant, instead of doing:

```
df = DataFrame(pd.read_csv(myfile.file))
```

You can do directly:

```
df = pd.read_csv(myfile.file)
```

Then to convert to float, and put whatever is not a number as NaN:

```
df = pd.to_numeric(df, errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried an alternative on the above:

```
for num, item in enumerate(data['col']):
    try:
        float(item)
    except:
        data['col'][num] = nan
```