# Having problems converting strings in a pandas series to lowercase

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, series, lowercase

I was able to do this in the DataFrame using a lambda function with map(lambda x: x.lower()). I tried to use a lambda function with pd.series.apply() but that didn't work. Also when I try to isolate the column in series with something like series['A'] should it return the index(although I guess this makes sense) because I get a float error even though the values that I want to apply the lower method to are strings. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you tried which was working for the entire DataFrame, perhaps `df.applymap(lambda x: x.lower() if isinstance(x, basestring) else x)` (Note: this is not very efficient).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Series vectorised string methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods), which includes lower:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B'], ['C', 4]], columns=['X', 'Y'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
   X  Y
0  A  B
1  C  4

In [13]: df.X.str.lower()
Out[13]: 
0    a
1    c
Name: X, dtype: object

In [14]: df.Y.str.lower()
Out[14]: 
0      b
1    NaN
Name: Y, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks. That is more concise than what I was using. I think I also found another problem. I was reading a csv with pd.read_csv. There were gaps, which read_csv filled with nan's which are floats and not strings, so I think that is why I got the error.

Comment: @user2592989 NaN is the placeholder for missing data used throughout pandas http://stackoverflow.com/a/17534682/1240268 (it's a float, so that explains it)

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower())` will do it on all columns