# Python Pandas isin return index

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` with a list of unique ids `id`, and a DataFrame with master list of all known ids `master_df.id`. I'm trying to figure out the best way to preform an `isin` that also returns to me the index where the value is located. So if my DataFrame was

`master_df` was

```
index id
1     1
2     2
3     3
```

and `df` was

```
index id
1     3
2     4
3     1
```

I want something like `(3, False, 1)`.
I'm currently doing an is in and then looking then brute forcing the lookup with a loop, but I'm sure there is a much better way to do it.

Comment: Is the index of `master_df` meaningful?  If you can make `master_df` have the id as its index, then you can just directly look the values up in `master_df`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to do a merge:

```
In [11]: df.merge(mdf, on='id', how='left')
Out[11]: 
   index_x  id  index_y
0        1   3        3
1        2   4      NaN
2        3   1        1
```

and column index_y is the desired result*:

```
In [12]: df.merge(mdf, on='id', how='left').index_y
Out[12]: 
0     3
1   NaN
2     1
Name: index_y, dtype: float64
```

* Except for NaN vs. False, but I think [NaN is what you really want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17534682/1240268) here. As @DSM points out, in python `False == 0` so you may get into trouble with False as the representative for missing vs being found with id 0. (If you still want to do it then replace the NaN with 0 using `.fillna(0)`).

Note: it's possible it will be more efficient to just take the columns you care about:

```
df[['id']].merge(mdf[['id', 'index']], on='id', how='left')
```

Comment: One point you didn't mention is that `False == 0`, which can easily get you into trouble.  `NaN` avoids this issue.

Comment: @DSM Excellent point, I realised this when I tried fillna, not sure why I neglected to mention it!