# Find all columns of dataframe in Pandas whose type is float, or a particular type?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe, df, that has some columns of type float64, while the others are of object. Due to the mixed nature, I cannot use

```
df.fillna('unknown') #getting error "ValueError: could not convert string to float:"
```

as the error happened with the columns whose type is float64 (what a misleading error message!)

so I'd wish that I could do something like

```
for col in df.columns[<dtype == object>]:
    df[col] = df[col].fillna("unknown")
```

So my question is if there is any such filter expression that I can use with df.columns?

I guess alternatively, less elegantly, I could do:

```
 for col in df.columns:
        if (df[col].dtype == dtype('O')): # for object type
            df[col] = df[col].fillna('') 
            # still puzzled, only empty string works as replacement, 'unknown' would not work for certain value leading to error of "ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "unknown" at position 0"
```

I also would like to know why in the above code replacing '' with 'unknown' the code would work for certain cells but failed with a cell with the error of "ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "unknown" at position 0"

Thanks a lot!

Yu

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can see what the dtype is for all the columns using the dtypes attribute:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a', 2.]])

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
   0  1  2
0  1  a  2

In [13]: df.dtypes
Out[13]: 
0      int64
1     object
2    float64
dtype: object

In [14]: df.dtypes == object
Out[14]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

To access the object columns:

```
In [15]: df.loc[:, df.dtypes == object]
Out[15]: 
   1
0  a
```

I think it's most explicit to use (I'm not *sure* that inplace would work here):

```
In [16]: df.loc[:, df.dtypes == object] = df.loc[:, df.dtypes == object].fillna('')
```

Saying that, I recommend you use [NaN for missing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534106/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-none/17534682#17534682).

Answer (score 91):

This is conciser:

```
# select the float columns
df_num = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.float])
# select non-numeric columns
df_num = df.select_dtypes(exclude=[np.number])
```

Comment: FYI, ``.select_dtypes`` came out in 0.14.1, IIRC @Andy soln was prior to that

Answer (score 10):

As @RNA said, you can use [pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html). The code using your example from a question would look like this:

```
for col in df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns:
    df[col] = df[col].fillna('unknown')
```