# Filling missing middle values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` as

```
Date  cost    NC
20     5   NaN
21     7   NaN
23     9  78.0
25     6  80.0
```

Now what I need to do is fillup the missing dates and hence fill the column with a value say `x` only if there is number in the previous row. That is I want the output like

```
Date  cost    NC
20     5   NaN
21     7   NaN
22     x   NaN
23     9  78.0
24     x   x
25     6  80.0
```

See Date 22 was missing and on 21 `NC` was missing, So on 22 `cost` is assigned to x but `NC` is assigned to `NaN`. Now setting the `Date` column to `index` and `reindex`ing it to missing values I can get upto here

```
Date  cost    NC 
20     5.0   NaN
21     7.0   NaN
22     NaN   NaN
23     9.0  78.0
24     NaN   NaN
25     6.0  80.0
```

But I cant get to the final output. If you think this way it is like `ffill()` but instead of filling from previous row you have to put `x` here.

I have another problem. here I have a dataframe `df` like this

```
Date type  cost
10    a    30
11    a    30
11    b    25
13    a    27
```

Here also I have to fill the missing value and make it like this

```
Date type cost
10    a   30
11    a   30
11    b   25
12    a   30
12    b   25
13    a   27
```

as you can see there was 2 data row for date 11 so both are copied to 12. I wrote this program for the problem

```
missing=[12]
for i in missing:
    new_date=i
    i-=1        #go to previous date
    k=df[df["Date"] == i].index.tolist()[-1]+1 #index where to be filled
    data=pd.DataFrame(df[df["Date"] == i].values,columns=df.columns)
    data["Date"]=new_date
    df=pd.concat([df.iloc[:k],data,df.iloc[k:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Now for a large data set the above program takes a lot of time as has to find index and concat 3 dataframe each time. Is there any better and efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: This is two separate questions. Please ask two separate questions!

Comment: Why do you want x rather than NaN?

Comment: because in my actual data I have some missing values and also some half filled column and I can not fill those places and the next where i am filling for missing dates. I exactly need what I posted

Comment: I asked 2 question here because I thought they might be related, one is putting `x` in missing and one is copying from row in missing. Also the next problem is more of "how to improve" like rather than "what is solution". So can I ask it here in SO or I have to ask it code review?

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it: Why not just use NaN for missing, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17534682/1240268. Using x is just going to give you a bad time. If they are distinct questions they should be asked separately - this helps others (searching for a solution similar to your problem), and stops the question being closed as "too broad".

Comment: In a simplified way let's say x=0 here and I want to fill the newly made missing value with 0 and keep the previous missing values

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to pad just the "middle" values, but here's a way to do it (using `ffill`, `bfill` and `fillna`):

```
In [11]: df1  # assuming Date is the index via df.set_index("Date")
Out[11]:
      cost    NC
Date
20       5   NaN
21       7   NaN
23       9  78.0
25       6  80.0

In [12]: df2 = df1.reindex(np.arange(20,27))
         # 26 is sufficient, but let's see it working!

In [13]: df2
Out[13]:
      cost    NC
Date
20     5.0   NaN
21     7.0   NaN
22     NaN   NaN
23     9.0  78.0
24     NaN   NaN
25     6.0  80.0
26     NaN   NaN
```

You don't want to fill in the "outside" NaNs, which can be got with:

```
In [14]: df2.bfill().notnull() & df2.ffill().notnull()
Out[14]:
       cost     NC
Date
20     True  False
21     True  False
22     True  False
23     True   True
24     True   True
25     True   True
26    False  False
```

Now, we can update these (if they would be updated with a `fillna`):

```
In [15]: df2[df2.bfill().notnull() & df2.ffill().notnull()] = df2.fillna(0) # x = 0

In [16]: df2
Out[15]:
      cost    NC
Date
20     5.0   NaN
21     7.0   NaN
22     0.0   NaN
23     9.0  78.0
24     0.0   0.0
25     6.0  80.0
26     NaN   NaN
```

---

To (partially) answer the second question, IMO you're always better off in that situation to start with a pivot (this will give you a much better starting point):

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
   Date type  cost
0    10    a    30
1    11    a    30
2    11    b    25
3    13    a    27

In [22]: df.pivot_table("cost", "Date", "type")
Out[22]:
type     a     b
Date
10    30.0   NaN
11    30.0  25.0
13    27.0   NaN
```

*Perhaps you are looking to fill forward from there? (and unstack if necessary).*

Comment: Can you also post how to get back to the final dataframe from this pivot table. I am trying `unstack` but I cant get it done

Comment: @Eular One way to do the latter is `df.pivot_table("cost", "Date", "type").ffill().stack().reset_index(name="cost")`

Comment: thanks for the 1st answer, I actually needed this `df[df.ffill().notnull()] = df.fillna(0)`. Here also i am confused why this works but this `df=df[df.ffill().notnull()].fillna(0)` doesnot again for a single column `df["NC"]=df[df["NC"].ffill().notnull()]["NC"].fillna(0)` this works

Comment: for the 2nd solution I did this `df.pivot_table(index="Date",columns='type').reindex([10,11,12,13],method="pad").stack().reset_index()`  which works perfectly.