# Convert only the nans between the first and the last populated value of each column

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a number of dataframes that look like the example below:

- each row is a period of observation each column is a quantity I am measuring (e.g. rainfall in New York)
- some columns starts and end with some nans
- most columns have nans in between the first and the last populated value

**Desired output**: for each column, convert the nans between the first and the last value to 0, without modifying the nans at the beginning and at the end

**Example**: convert `[nan,7,6,nan,9,nan]` to `[nan,7,6,0,9,nan]`

**What I have tried:**

based on [Locate first and last non NaN values in a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403469/locate-first-and-last-non-nan-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe) it's easy to find the first and the last not-null value for each column
I can therefore loop through each column, then for each column loop between first and last not-null values, and replace nans with zero. **It works, but it is of course not vectorised, slow and inefficient.**

Can you think of a better alternative?

I could, for each column, query the dataframe to find the nans between the first and last, but I would still have to loop through all the columns.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(5)
import pandas as pd

rows = 20
df =pd.DataFrame(index = np.arange(0,rows), columns =['New York', 'London','Paris'], data = np.random.rand(rows,3))

df.iloc[0:2,0] = np.nan
df.iloc[0:3,1] = np.nan


df.iloc[-3:,0] = np.nan
df.iloc[-2:,1] = np.nan

df.iloc[7,0] = np.nan
df.iloc[10,0] = np.nan

df.iloc[9,1] = np.nan

df.iloc[11,2] = np.nan

first_notna = df.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index)
last_notna = df.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index)

out = df.copy()

for numcol, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    for r in np.arange( first_notna.loc[col], last_notna.loc[col] + 1 ):
        if np.isnan( df.iloc[r,numcol]):
            out.iloc[r,numcol] = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Copying a solution from another stack overflow answer: [Filling missing middle values in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821653/filling-missing-middle-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

Uses a combination of bfill and ffill to first get a boolean df of whether the row is NOT a trailing or leading nan. It then fills those with 0

```
df[df.bfill().notnull() & df.ffill().notnull()] = df.fillna(0)
```

Comment: Also `df[df.bfill().notnull() & df.ffill().notnull() & df.isna()] = 0`.

Comment: @Quang Hoang - That will make all not null rows to 0 instead.

Comment: what not null rows? There's extra `df.isna()` condition, which is equivalent to `df.fillna(0)` in your code :-)

Comment: Oops - sorry I didn't see that. My bad!