# Pandas. Replace nan with None

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I'm using Pandas to parse a csv and I'm reading nan values from an excel and I'd like to convert them to None.

```
season_matches = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(rv.decode('utf-8')))
season_matches = season_matches.replace(np.nan, None)
season_matches = season_matches.to_dict()
```

This however returns `TypeError: cannot replace [nan] with method pad on a DataFrame`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/17534106/1240268