# Pandas: difference between NaN and None

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What's the difference between a cell value of `NaN` and `None`? I used `df.dropna()`, which drops all `NaN` but I still have a lot of `None`.

I am wondering what's the difference between them and how do I get rid of `None` as well?

Thanks!

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534106/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-none#17534682

Answer (score 0):

@szeitlin already gave a link to a  similar question, but if you need this: you can convert a NaN to None

```
df1 = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)
```

or None to NaN:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(x)
x = x.astype(float)
```