# Why does pandas isnull() work but ==None not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to select the rows of `df` where the column `label` has value `None`. (It's value `None` I obtained from another function, not `NaN`)

Why does `df[df['label'].isnull()]` return the rows I wanted,

but `df[df['label'] == None]` returns `Empty DataFrame
Columns: [path, fanId, label, gain, order]
Index: []` ?

Comment: Because... np.nan == None returns False.  You need ot use isnull or isna to check for missing data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the comment above states, missing data in `pandas` is represented by a *NaN*, where *NaN* is a numerical value, i.e float type. However *None* is a Python `NoneType`, so *NaN* will not be equivalent to *None*.

```
In [27]: np.nan == None
Out[27]: False
```

In this [Github thread](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20442) they discuss further, noting:

> This was done quite a while ago to make the behavior of nulls consistent, in that they don't compare equal. This puts None and np.nan on an equal (though not-consistent with python, BUT consistent with numpy) footing.

This means when you do `df[df['label'] == None]`, you're going `elementwise` checking if `np.nan == np.nan`, which we know is false.

```
In [63]: np.nan == np.nan
Out[63]: False
```

Additionally you should not do `df[df['label'] == None]` when you're applying [Boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html), using `==` for a `NoneType` is not best practice as [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) mentions:

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with `is` or `is not`, never the equality operators.

For example you could do `tst.value.apply(lambda  x: x is None)`, which yields the same outcome as `.isnull()`, illustrating how `pandas` treats these as *NaN*s. **Note** this is for the below `tst` dataframe example, where `tst.value.dtypes` is an `object` of which I've explicitly specified the `NoneType` elements.

There is a nice [example](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/missing_data.html#inserting-missing-data) in the `pandas` docs which illustrate this and it's effect.

For example if you have two columns, one of type `float` and the other `object` you can see how pandas deals with the `None` type in a nice way, notice for `float` it is using *NaN*.

```
In [32]: tst = pd.DataFrame({"label" : [1, 2, None, 3, None], "value" : ["A", "B", None, "C", None]})

Out[39]:
   label value
0    1.0     A
1    2.0     B
2    NaN  None
3    3.0     C
4    NaN  None

In [51]: type(tst.value[2])
Out[51]: NoneType

In [52]: type(tst.label[2])
Out[52]: numpy.float64
```

**This post explains the difference between *NaN* and *None* really well**, would definitely take a look at this.

- [What is the difference between NaN and None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534106/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-none)

Comment: Preferred is `.isnull()`, `==` does not work as in `pandas` it is equivalent to comparing `np.nan == np.nan` which will return *False*, as in my example above if you did `tst[tst.value == None]` you will get an empty data.frame

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but *you stated* that `tst.value.apply(lambda  x: x is None)` is a better alternative to `df['label'] == None`, which is definitely not true.

Comment: No, I was illustrating what good practices is when comparing singletons, and then gave an example, I said *could* not *should* when doing the comparison in `pandas`...

Comment: But **why would you do that**? It would be *worse* than using `==`.

Comment: It's an illustration, I'm not saying you should do it, rather to show how the `NoneTypes` exist in the `pandas.DataFrame` however when doing a vectorized comparison it's going to yield the same result as `np.nan == np.nan` as that's how pandas treats the `None`

Comment: Ahhhh yes. I see what you were trying to illustrate here, subtle point.