# What's the string equivalent of np.nan?

Tags: python, pandas, null, nan

I have a dataframe, and want to add a blank column. If it's for numbers, I would use `df["new_column"] = pd.np.nan`. But what if I want the column to (a) hold strings, and (b) be filterable with `pd.isnull()`? Is there a better idea than `df["new_column"] = ""`?

Comment: You can use None keyword

Comment: `pd.isnull` plays nicely with strings (unlike `np.isnan`, which throws an error). Why not just use `np.nan`?

Comment: @Fortunato, because Python will throw an exception when you try to insert a string into the column initialized with `pd.nan`

Comment: @DimitriShvorob, I'm probably misunderstanding what you are trying to do. can you provide an example? this seems to work fine for me: `a=pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=['col1', 'col2']); a['new_col'] = pd.np.nan; a['new_col'].iloc[0] = 'p'`

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that Python doesn't have a Null string. Python does have a None value but it isn't a string it is A None that can be applied to all variables - not just those which are originally defined as a string.

You could use NoneType but the column would then not be a string but an object type. You could still insert strings in the column, but changing the type of the column to string would simply consider None values as the string 'None'

please see this too: [What is the difference between NaN and None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534106/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-none)

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'numbers_column':np.nan,
                             'strings_column':[None, None, None,'random_str']},
                              index=[1,2,3, 4])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Pandas doesn't use a string type, it uses object

Comment: There is, but it is considered experimental: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.StringDtype.html