# How to create dataframe in pandas that contains Null values

Tags: python, pandas

I try to create below dataframe that deliberately lacks some piece of information. That is, `type` shall be empty for one record.

```
df = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      'created_at': ['2020-02-01', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-03'],
      'type': ['red', NaN, 'blue', 'blue', 'yellow']}

df = pd.DataFrame (df, columns = ['id', 'created_at','type', 'converted_tf'])
```

Works perfectly fine when I put all the values but I keep getting errors with `NaN`, `Null`, `Na`,  etc.

Any idea what I have to put?

Comment: Use `None` instead.

Comment: Yepp, `None` was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NaN`, `Null`, `Na` doesn't not represent an absence of value.

---

Use *Python's* [***`None`***](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/none.html) Object to represent absence of value.

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      'created_at': ['2020-02-01', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-03'],
      'type': ['red', None, 'blue', 'blue', 'yellow']}

df = pd.DataFrame (df, columns = ['id', 'created_at','type', 'converted_tf'])
```

If you try to print the df, you'll get the following output:

```
   id  created_at    type converted_tf
0   1  2020-02-01     red          NaN
1   2  2020-02-02    None          NaN
2   3  2020-02-02    blue          NaN
3   4  2020-02-02    blue          NaN
4   5  2020-02-03  yellow          NaN
```

So, you may now think that `NaN` and `None` are different. Pandas uses `NaN` as a placeholder for missing values, i.e instead of showing None it shows `NaN` which is more readable. Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17534682/3091398).

Now let's trying fillna function,

```
df.fillna('')  # filling None or NaN values with empty string
```

You can see that both `NaN` and `None` got replaced by empty string.

```
   id  created_at    type converted_tf
0   1  2020-02-01     red
1   2  2020-02-02
2   3  2020-02-02    blue
3   4  2020-02-02    blue
4   5  2020-02-03  yellow
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `np.NaN` if need missing value:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      'created_at': ['2020-02-01', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-03'],
      'type': ['red', np.NaN, 'blue', 'blue', 'yellow']}
```

Or `float('NaN')` working too:

```
df = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      'created_at': ['2020-02-01', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-03'],
      'type': ['red', float('NaN'), 'blue', 'blue', 'yellow']}
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame (df, columns = ['id', 'created_at','type', 'converted_tf'])
print (df)
   id  created_at    type converted_tf
0   1  2020-02-01     red          NaN
1   2  2020-02-02     NaN          NaN
2   3  2020-02-02    blue          NaN
3   4  2020-02-02    blue          NaN
4   5  2020-02-03  yellow          NaN
```

Or use `None`, it most time working same like `np.NaN` if processing data in pandas:

```
df = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      'created_at': ['2020-02-01', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-03'],
      'type': ['red', None, 'blue', 'blue', 'yellow']}

df = pd.DataFrame (df, columns = ['id', 'created_at','type', 'converted_tf'])
print (df)
   id  created_at    type converted_tf
0   1  2020-02-01     red          NaN
1   2  2020-02-02    None          NaN
2   3  2020-02-02    blue          NaN
3   4  2020-02-02    blue          NaN
4   5  2020-02-03  yellow          NaN
```