# How to separate between empty string, np.nan and None when using to_excel(...) function for pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel, nonetype

After constructing data frame `df` containing `np.nan`, `None` and empty string (`''`) values in Python 3.8.3 and Pandas 1.0.4

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'b':None,'c':''},index=[0])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':1,'b':1,'c':None},index=[0])
df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0, sort=True)
print(df)
```

data frame `df` looks like

```
     a     b     c
0  NaN  None      
0  1.0     1  None
```

Now I would like to store the values to Excel using `to_excel()` function. However, after running command

```
df.to_excel('nan_none_empty.xlsx')
```

the result rather looks like

[image: excel_picture]

with `np.nan`, `None` and empty string (`''`) not being separable from each other.

It is possible to separate empty string (`''`) from `np.nan` and `None` with option `na_rep` as follows

```
df.to_excel('nan_none_empty2.xlsx',na_rep='?')
```

giving result

[image]

But it seems like, for this problem, I am running out of [options for to_excel(...) function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.4/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) in order to be able to separate `np.nan` from `None` in the Excel export.

How could one neatly separate between `np.nan` and `None` when exporting `df` to Excel?

Comment: Seems like `df.fillna(value='?')` replaces both `np.nan` and `None` with `'?'`. Therefore, `df.fillna` cannot be used to solve the problem.

Comment: take a look at [the difference between NaN and None in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17534106/6692898), it seems there is no way to distinguish them

Comment: Out of curiousity, why would you want to make this distinguishment? These all look like missing values

Comment: I am trying to show a dictionary containing samples of facts in a matrix: (i) value `None` means that corresponding fact sample `{'b':None,'c':''}` had an element `b` with `None` value, (ii) value `np.nan`, means that the corresponding fact sample `{'b':None,'c':''}` did not contain element `'a'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to distinguish between different null types, your best bet is to replace values *before* exporting to Excel. Converting to a string is one way to make sure you are not conflating None, np.NaN, pd.NaT, etc...

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'b':None,'c':''},index=[0])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':1,'b':1,'c':None},index=[0])
df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0, sort=True)

null_map = {'nan': '-',
            'None': '?'} # Add the string representation for other types you may need

df = df.applymap(lambda x:
                 null_map[str(x)]
                 if str(x) in null_map
                 else x)
df.to_excel('nan_none_empty2.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: str(x) if x in [None, ''] else x)
df.to_excel('nan_none_empty.xlsx',na_rep='np.nan')
```