# How to convert type to bool in pandas with `None` values in the series?

Tags: python, pandas, types, boolean

Why does the value `None` convert to both `True` and `False` in this series?

Env:

- Jupyter Notebok 6.0.3 in Jupyter Labs
- Python 3.7.6

Imports:

```
from IPython.display import display
import pandas as pd
```

Converts `None` to `True`:

```
df_test1 = pd.DataFrame({'test_column':[0,1,None]})
df_test1['test_column'] = df_test1.test_column.astype(bool)
display(df_test1)
```

[image]

Converts `None` to `False`:

```
df_test2 = pd.DataFrame({'test_column':[0,1,None,'test']})
df_test2['test_column'] = df_test2.test_column.astype(bool)
display(df_test2)
```

[image]

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: `bool(np.nan)` is what your first case is whereas `bool(None)` is your second example, try `df_test1['prime_member'].apply(type)` v/s `df_test2['prime_member'].apply(type)`

Comment: Good read : [What is the difference between NaN and None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534106/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-none)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behaviour, it leads from the initial `dtype` storage type of each series (column). The first input results in a series with *floating point numbers*, the second contains references to *Python objects*:

```py
>>> pd.Series([0,1,None]).dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> pd.Series([0,1,None,'test']).dtype
dtype('O')
```

The float version of `None` is NaN, or *Not a Number*, which converts to True when interpreted as a boolean (as it is not equal to 0):

```py
>>> pd.Series([0,1,None])[2]
nan
>>> bool(pd.Series([0,1,None])[2])
True
```

In the other case, the original `None` object was preserved, which converts to `False`:

```py
>>> pd.Series([0,1,None,'test'])[2] is None
True
>>> bool(None)
False
```

So this comes down to *automatic type inference*, what type Pandas thinks is best suited for each column; see the [`DataFrame.infer_objects()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html). The goal is to minimise storage requirements and operation performance; storing numbers as native 64-bit floating point values leads to faster numeric operations and a smaller memory footprint, while at the same time still being able to represent 'missing' values as NaN.

However, when you pass in a mix of numbers and strings, Panda's can't use a dedicated specialised array type and so falls back to the "Python object" type, which are references to the original Python objects.

Instead of letting Pandas *guess* as to what type you need, you could explicitly specify the type to be used. You could use one of the [nullable integer types](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/arrays.html#api-arrays-integer-na) (which use `Pandas.NA` instead of NaN); converting these to booleans results in missing values converting to `False`:

```py
>>> pd.Series([0,1,None], dtype=pd.Int64Dtype).astype(bool)
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Another option is to convert to a [*nullable boolean type*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.BooleanDtype.html), and so preserve the `None` / NaN indicators of missing data:

```py
>>> pd.Series([0,1,None]).astype("boolean")
0    False
1     True
2     <NA>
dtype: boolean
```

Also see [*Working with missing data*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html) section in the user manual, as well as the [*nullable integer*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) and [*nullable boolean*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/boolean.html) data type manual pages.

Note that the Pandas notion of the `NA` value, representing *missing data*, is [still considered experimental](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#missing-data-na), which is why it is not yet the default. But if you want to 'opt in' for dataframes you just created, you can call the [`DataFrame.convert_dtypes()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes) right after creating the frame:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'prime_member':[0,1,None]}).convert_dtypes()
>>> df.prime_member
0       0
1       1
2    <NA>
Name: prime_member, dtype: Int64
```

Answer (score 5):

The differences are datatypes `df_test1.prime_member.dtype` is `float64`, and you don't have `None`, but `NaN`. Now, `bool(np.nan)` is `True`.

However, when you have mixed type column: `df_test2.prime_member.dtype` is `object`. Then `None` remains `None` in the data, and `bool(None)` is `False`.