# Automatically converting Decimal to float in Pandas read_sql without converting None to zero or Nan

Tags: python, sql, pandas

When using `read_sql` in pandas, some None data from DB will be converted to 0/Nan, while other None stay as None.

- Q #1:  how does pandas determine when to convert None to zero or None to Nan, and when not to convert None (leave as is)

I understand that I can set `coerce_float=False` to disable this auto-conversion.

- Q #2 I wonder, is there a way to just avoid converting `None` data but still try converting other not-None data?

Note:

1. Sorry, I don't have the required reputation to add `pandas` tag.  Please help if you can.

Comment: I would assume that pandas would convert None to NaN in cases where "None" is a placeholder for missing value. If it's a string, for example, it should be read as-is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534106/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-none