# What is the difference between Null Nan and None in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am stuck at a point in python where dataset has None values and It was working fine when there was nan in the dataset, Now it's saying argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'.

```
   a = NaN
    if (a is None):
        print('a is None')
    elif(a is NaN):
        print('a is NaN')
    elif(a is None):
        print('a is Null')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534106/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-none

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between NaN and None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534106/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-none)