# Why numpy.nan is different than math.nan?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math, nan

Why is `math.nan` different than `numpy.nan`?

```
>>> import math
>>> import numpy as np
>>> math.nan is math.nan
True
>>> np.nan is np.nan
True
>>> np.nan is math.nan
False
```

What is the point of having two different NaNs?

Comment: They were created separately, so they're separate objects. They have the same value (even if that value is not equal to itself).

Comment: It gets worse than that: `np.nan == np.nan` returns `False`.

Comment: NaN is not a singleton.  NaN is a bit pattern that has a special interpretation (actually, there are many different NaNs, since a NaN can have a "payload").  There can be multiple instances of the same NaN, just like there can be multiple instances of, say, 1.0.  Try this: `x = 1.0; y = 1.0; print(x is y)`.  The output is False.

Comment: @Stef Also `math.nan == math.nan` also returns `False`.

Comment: And `float('NaN') == float('NaN')` also returns `False`, although I don't know if that differs from `math.nan` is implemented.

Comment: NaN == NaN *should* return false. That's how NaN behavior is defined in IEEE 754 and most languages that use it. Like, "NaN is not equal to any numeric value, including other NaNs". It's "three-valued logic", like SQL NULLs. Related to how Warren talks about NaNs being a class of values, not just one specific value or bit pattern. Need to use `isnan()` tests and compare those results if you want to see if two values are both NaNs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*What is the point of having two different NaNs?*

Disclaimer: I assume you want to know why there is `math.nan` and `numpy.nan`, if this does not hold true ignore this answer entirely.

This is due to historical reasons, [math docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) inform that `math.nan` is

> New in version 3.5.

NumPy is older than that, [PyPI NumPy release history](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#history) shows that version 1.0 was released in **October 2006**, whilst according to [PEP 478](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0478/) first final version for Python 3.5.0 was scheduled for **September 2015**, therefore creators of NumPy have not possibility of usage of `math.nan`. This lead to question why `nan` was added to `math` if it is already in `numpy`. This might be explained simply: `math` is built-in module, whilst `numpy` is not.

As side note you might also craft `NaN` without any `import`s in python, just do `float("NaN")`.