None and Nan in pandas dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[None]})
s = df1.to_json(orient='table')
df2 = pd.read_json(io.StringIO(s), orient='table')

df1 is
    a
0   None

df2 is
    a
0   NaN

Why are they different?
df1.equals(df2) evals to true. Are None and Nan interchangeable in pandas dataframe?

Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534106/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-none

None and NaN are entirely different concepts. The Numpy documentation for NaN (which is the underlying type) points to the IEEE 754 floating point number representation standard, which you can read about on Wikipedia.

See also Python's docs on None, a built-in object to represent the absence of value.

Pandas considers both NaN and None values to be NA, not available. Therefore the equality above demonstrates that both types are NA.
The docs covering NA semantics explain this in depth.
A specific example using a nullable integer dtype (from the linked docs above):
In [21]: s = pd.Series([1, 2, None], dtype="Int64")

In [22]: s
Out[22]: 
0       1
1       2
2    <NA>
dtype: Int64

In [23]: s[2]
Out[23]: <NA>

In [24]: s[2] is pd.NA
Out[24]: True

