# Convert pandas.Series from dtype object to float, and errors to nans

Tags: python, pandas, nan

Consider the following situation:

```
In [2]: a = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,'.'])

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    .
dtype: object

In [8]: a.astype('float64', raise_on_error = False)
Out[8]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    .
dtype: object
```

I would have expected an option that allows conversion while turning erroneous values (such as that `.`) to `NaN`s. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

#### Use [`pd.to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`

```
# Setup
s = pd.Series(['1', '2', '3', '4', '.'])
s

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    .
dtype: object
```

```
pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')

0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```

If you need the `NaN`s filled in, use [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html).

```
pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').fillna(0, downcast='infer')

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    0
dtype: float64
```

Note, `downcast='infer'` will attempt to downcast floats to integers where possible. Remove the argument if you don't want that.

> From v0.24+, pandas introduces a [Nullable Integer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) type, which allows
>   integers to coexist with NaNs. If you have integers in your column,
>   you can use
>
> ```
> pd.__version__
> # '0.24.1'
>
> pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').astype('Int32')
>
> 0      1
> 1      2
> 2      3
> 3      4
> 4    NaN
> dtype: Int32
> ```
>
> There are other options to choose from as well, read the docs for more.

---

#### **Extension for `DataFrames`**

If you need to extend this to DataFrames, you will need to *apply* it to each row. You can do this using [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

```
# Setup.
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : np.random.choice(10, 5), 
    'C' : np.random.choice(10, 5), 
    'B' : ['1', '###', '...', 50, '234'], 
    'D' : ['23', '1', '...', '268', '$$']}
)[list('ABCD')]
df

   A    B  C    D
0  5    1  9   23
1  0  ###  3    1
2  3  ...  5  ...
3  3   50  2  268
4  7  234  4   $$

df.dtypes

A     int64
B    object
C     int64
D    object
dtype: object
```

```
df2 = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df2

   A      B  C      D
0  5    1.0  9   23.0
1  0    NaN  3    1.0
2  3    NaN  5    NaN
3  3   50.0  2  268.0
4  7  234.0  4    NaN

df2.dtypes

A      int64
B    float64
C      int64
D    float64
dtype: object
```

You can also do this with [`DataFrame.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html#pandas.DataFrame.transform); although my tests indicate this is marginally slower:

```
df.transform(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

   A      B  C      D
0  5    1.0  9   23.0
1  0    NaN  3    1.0
2  3    NaN  5    NaN
3  3   50.0  2  268.0
4  7  234.0  4    NaN
```

If you have many columns (numeric; non-numeric), you can make this a little more performant by applying `pd.to_numeric` on the non-numeric columns only.

```
df.dtypes.eq(object)

A    False
B     True
C    False
D     True
dtype: bool

cols = df.columns[df.dtypes.eq(object)]
# Actually, `cols` can be any list of columns you need to convert.
cols
# Index(['B', 'D'], dtype='object')

df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
# Alternatively,
# for c in cols:
#     df[c] = pd.to_numeric(df[c], errors='coerce')

df

   A      B  C      D
0  5    1.0  9   23.0
1  0    NaN  3    1.0
2  3    NaN  5    NaN
3  3   50.0  2  268.0
4  7  234.0  4    NaN
```

Applying `pd.to_numeric` along the columns (i.e., `axis=0`, the default) should be slightly faster for long DataFrames.

Comment: This is awesome :-) , We should keep the thing updated , since left deprecated method on this site is not good for the future visitor :-) , You did it

Comment: Aha, maybe you can add `s.str.isalnum()` :-) combine with `mask`

Comment: @Wen You mean `s.str.isdigit()`? It will only work for integers, not floats. Good idea though.

Comment: @Wen as per I know `to_numeric` is gold here.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ as of reference we can take this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/47001413/4800652 to consideration.

Comment: Thanks! However, using axis=0 yields an error in my Python 3.6.2:   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2294, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 1207, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:66124)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2282, in <lambda>
    f = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwds)
TypeError: to_numeric() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Answer (score 20):

```
In [30]: pd.Series([1,2,3,4,'.']).convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[30]: 
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I think I took out the function of ``raise_on_error`` a while back. Doesn't do anything ATM.

Comment: I opened an issue for enhancement here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8332, feel free to comment on proposed API

Comment: On 0.14.1 it prevents it from throwing an exception. Without specifying it the `astype` statement would've raise an error.

Comment: sorry you are right. That's why never JUST read the code, test it :)

Comment: `.convert_objects()` method has been deprecated since 0.17, [`pd.to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) is the new way to go.

Answer (score -2):

Do this:

pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')

Comment: repetitive answer with no additional effort