# Plots do not appear when calling seaborn's pairplot on a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I have a Dataframe that looks like so

```
Price   Mileage Age
4250    71000   8
6500    43100   6
26950   10000   3
1295    78000   17
5999    61600   8
```

This is assigned to `dataset`. I simply call `sns.pairplot(dataset)` and I'm left with just a single graph - the distribution of prices across my dataset. I expected a 3x3 grid of plots.

When I import a pre-configured dataset from seaborn I get the expected multiplot pair plot.

I'm new to seaborn so apologies if this is a silly question, but what am I doing wrong? It seems like a simple task.

Comment: What is `df.dtypes`?

Comment: ah ha! It's -
Price       int64
Mileage    object
Age        object
dtype: object

Comment: Im guessing those objects need to be ints! Thank you

Comment: Probably not int, because you may have invalid values in your dataframe. You can either coerce them to NaN, or drop them and convert to int.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, it seems like you're trying to plot on non-numeric columns. [Try coercing them first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952790/convert-pandas-series-from-dtype-object-to-float-and-errors-to-nans):

```
dataset = dataset.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
sns.pairplot(dataset)
```

The `errors='coerce'` argument will replace non-coercible values (the reason your columns are objects in the first place) to NaN.