# combining real and imag columns in dataframe into complex number to obtain magnitude using np.abs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, complex-numbers

I have a data frame that has complex numbers split into a real and an imaginary column.  I want to add a column (2, actually, one for each channel) to the dataframe that computes the log magnitude:

```
 `    ch1_real  ch1_imag  ch2_real  ch2_imag  ch1_phase  ch2_phase  distance
79   0.011960 -0.003418  0.005127 -0.019530     -15.95    -75.290       0.0
78  -0.009766 -0.005371 -0.015870  0.010010    -151.20    147.800       1.0
343  0.002197  0.010990  0.003662 -0.013180      78.69    -74.480       2.0
80  -0.002686  0.010740  0.011960  0.013430     104.00     48.300       3.0
341 -0.007080  0.009033  0.016600 -0.000977     128.10     -3.366       4.0
```

If I try this:

```
df['ch1_log_mag']=20*np.log10(np.abs(complex(df.ch1_real,df.ch1_imag)))
```

I get error: "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>", because I think cmath.complex cannot work on an array.

So I then experimented using loc to pick out the first element of ch1_real, for example, to then work out how use it to accomplish what I'm trying to do, but couldn't figure out how to do it:

```
df.loc[0,df['ch1_real']]
```

This produces a KeyError.

Brute forcing it works,

```
df['ch1_log_mag'] = 20 * np.log10(np.sqrt(df.ch1_real**2+ df.ch1_imag**2))
```

but, I believe it is more legible to use np.abs to get the magnitude, plus I'm more interested in understanding how dataframes and indexing dataframes work and why what I initially attempted does not work.

btw, what is the difference between df.ch1_real and df['ch1_real'] ?  When do I use one vs. the other?

**Edit**:  more attempts at solution
I tried using apply, since my understanding is that it "applies" the function passed to it to each row (by default):

```
df.apply(complex(df['ch1_real'], df['ch1_imag']))
```

but this generates the same TypeError, since I think the issue is that complex cannot work on Series.  Perhaps if I cast the series to float?

After reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952790/convert-pandas-series-from-dtype-object-to-float-and-errors-to-nans), I tried using pd.to_numeric to convert a series to  type float:

```
 dfUnique.apply(complex(pd.to_numeric(dfUnique['ch1_real'],errors='coerce'), pd.to_numeric(dfUnique['ch1_imag'],errors='coerce')))
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do simple multiplication with `1j` which denotes the complex number `0+1j`, see [imaginary literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#imaginary-literals):

```
df['ch1_log_mag'] = 20 * np.log10((df.ch1_real + 1j * df.ch1_imag).abs())
```

`complex(df.ch1_real, df.ch1_imag)` doesn't work as it needs a float argument, not a whole series. `df.loc[0,df['ch1_real']]` is not a valid expression, as the second argument must be a string, not a series (df.loc[79,'ch1_real'] would work for accessing an element).
If you want to use `apply` it should be `20 * np.log10(df.apply(lambda x: complex(x.ch1_real, x.ch1_imag), 1).abs())` but as apply is just a disguised loop over the rows of the dataframe it's not recommended performancewise.

There's no difference between `df.ch1_real` and `df['ch1_real']`, it's a matter of personal preference. If your column name contains spaces or dots or the like you must use the latter form however.

Comment: thank you, this works.  But, can you explain why what I was trying doesn't work?  I looking for more than just an answer--I'd like to understand this a little better.

Comment: @jrive: please see my updated answer for additional comments on the errors and `apply`.