# Pandas DataFrame Replace NaT with None

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have been struggling with this question for a long while, and I tried different methods.

I have a simple DataFrame as shown,

[image]

I can use code to replace `NaN` with `None` (Not String "None"),

`[![dfTest2 = dfTest.where(pd.notnull(dfTest), None)][2]][2]`

[image]

I support  that `NaT` is also classified as 'Null' because the following,
 [image]

However, `NaT` is not replaced with `None`.

I have been searching for answers but got no luck. Anyone could Help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any luck with `df.fillna(None)`?

Comment: @Cleb, tried but not won't work. Exception as `ValueError: must specify a fill method or value`. Seems that `None` is either an value or method.

Comment: [This might be of help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097236/how-to-replace-values-with-none-in-pandas-data-frame-in-python).

Comment: @Cleb Hi, Thx for the reference. Please see the answer below.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42818550/8770481 This one saved my life. It worked well for me

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Make the `dtype` `object`

```
dfTest2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(InvoiceDate=pd.to_datetime(['2017-06-01', pd.NaT])))

dfTest2.InvoiceDate.astype(object).where(dfTest2.InvoiceDate.notnull(), None)

0    2017-06-01 00:00:00
1                   None
Name: InvoiceDate, dtype: object
```

Comment: Amazing!!! Thank you so so much. Totally make sense, the Timestamp type gives default  NaT for Null.  Thx again.

Comment: I don't wanna change the type of object and want it only in datetime format so this solution isn't working for me.

Comment: Your code gives me only the column affected as a result. But I want this to happen in in the DF itself and the original column replaced by this new one with None's. How to do that?

Comment: Assign the result back to the dataframe

Answer (score 34):

The simplest solution I found that worked for me is...

**Input:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dfTest = pd.DataFrame(dict(InvoiceDate=pd.to_datetime(['2017-06-01', pd.NaT]), CorpId=[2997373, np.nan], TestName=[1,1]))
dfTest.replace({np.nan: None}, inplace = True)
```

**Output of dfTest:**

[image]

Comment: Note that `pd.np` was removed in Pandas 1.x.x

Comment: This also changes the column type to object

Answer (score 7):

`df.fillna(None)` only works for `np.na` but not `pd.NaT`. However doing `df.replace({np.nan: None})` replaces both `pd.NaT` and `np.na` with `None`.

```
# Initalize a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
                    'start_date': pd.to_datetime(['2017-06-01', pd.NaT]), 
                    'amount':[2997373, np.nan]
                   })
display(df)

# Then replace pd.NaT and np.na with None
df = df.replace({np.nan: None})
display(df)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the one that finally did it for me! Interestingly, `df.replace(np.nan, None)` has the same effect as `df.fillna(None)`, but converting the `replace` call to a dict apparently makes all the difference.

Comment: I was mad why not working for me, I was using pandas version 1.4. Upgraded to 1.5 or latest it worked!

Answer (score 5):

**Make the column type as str first**

```
 dfTest2.InvoiceDate =  dfTest2.InvoiceDate.astype(str)
```

**then compare it directly with "NaT" and replace with None**

```
dfTest2.InvoiceDate = dfTest2.InvoiceDate.apply(lambda x : None if x=="NaT" else x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar approach as suggested by @neerajYadav but without the `apply`:

```
dfTest2['InvoiceDate'] = (dfTest2['InvoiceDate']
                          .astype(str) # <- cast to string to simplify
                                       #    .replace() in newer versions
                          .replace({'NaT': None} # <- replace with None
                         )
```

Comment: This will change the column type to str, which in some cases we don't want that to happen

Answer (score 1):

So I'm a little late to the party, but this result also worked for me.

`

```
import pandas as pd

df["column"] = df["column"].replace({pd.NaT: None})
```

`

Answer (score 0):

This looks strange but worked for me.
Pandas version 14.1

```
import numpy as np

df = df.replace(np.NaN, 0).replace(0, None)
```

Before
LastModifiedDate
**NaT**

After
LastModifiedDate
**None**

Comment: This cannot be correct. When `to_replace=` is a scalar and `value=` is `None` (as in your second `.replace()` call above), the function uses the `method=` parameter (see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) and [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17494#issuecomment-328966324) Github issue comment), which means forward-filling last non-null (and non-0 in your case).

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of other similar answers here, though none are as simple as this:

```
df.replace([pd.NaT], [None])
```

Answer (score 0):

dfTest2.replace({pd.NaT:None},inplace=True)

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to change the type of the column, then another alternative is to to replace all missing values (`pd.NaT`) first with `np.nan` and then replace the latter with `None`:

```
import numpy as np

df = df.fillna(np.nan).replace([np.nan], [None])
```

Comment: `df.fillna(np.nan)` does not replace `NaT` with `nan`.

Comment: why not just `df.replace([pd.NaT], [None])`