# NaN replace on pandas DataFrame raises TypeError: No matching signature found

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, elasticsearch

## Purpose

I have a large DataFrame with varied dtypes where I have to perform a global `.replace` to turn *both NaN, NaT and empty strings* into `None`. The DataFrame looks like

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [n*10.0 for n in range(5)],
    'b': [datetime.now() if n%3 else None for n in range(5)],
    'c': pd.Series([f'D{n}' if n%2 else '' for n in range(5)], dtype='category'),
    'd': ['Long text chunk...' if n%3 else None for n in range(5)]
})
```

Which prints

```py
      a                          b   c                   d
0   0.0                        NaT                    None
1  10.0 2020-08-13 23:35:55.533189  D1  Long text chunk...
2  20.0 2020-08-13 23:35:55.533189      Long text chunk...
3  30.0                        NaT  D3                None
4  40.0 2020-08-13 23:35:55.533189      Long text chunk...
```

My purpose is to bulk upload the rows into ElasticSearch, which won't accept NaN - neither NaT nor empty strings for date fields - without some setting changes I'm trying to avoid. I figured this way would be faster than individually checking every row when making the dicts.

## Approach

[Converting all columns to `object`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42818550/8272600) before replacing wasn't even runnable due to the DataFrame size - I'd prefer not to convert any column at all. An approach that once worked was

```py
df.fillna('').replace('', None)
```

But now, adding some category dtypes in, it raises `TypeError: No matching signature found`.

## Question

Searching this, nothing I found was related to `pandas` at all. It's clearly linked to the category dtype¹, but what I don't know:

- What's the most pythonic way of doing this while keeping integrity for all columns, [especially the categorical ones](https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes_cat.html#watch-outs)?
- <strike>What happens behind the curtains for pandas to raise this apparently generic error in a `.replace`?</strike>

---

¹ Edit:

I later found that the pandas implementation replace in this case reaches up to a Cython-compiled method - `pandas._libs.algos.pad_inplace` - which expects to fill any Series dtype except `category`. That's why my error mentions a *signature* mismatch. I still wonder if this is intended behavior, as I'd expect an ffill to work especially well in categorical columns.

---

Since my numeric columns were filled already, I changed column `a` here to reflect that. So my hassle is solely the `category` dtype.

Comment: `None` is an object; a Series has to be object dtype to contain such an object.

Comment: The `float64` series gets converted.  Actually it's the `fillna` that converts all columns - except the category one.  Your replace works if the value is a valid 'category', e.g. `df.fillna('').replace('','D1')`.  I don't know anything abut `elasticsearch`.  But looking at your sample `df`, I see that the 'c' column is a unique pandas structure, which probably isn't usable outside of `pandas`.

Comment: @hpaulj wow, I can see how obvious it is now that you've said it... My question could qualify as practical duplicate (to the very link I mention above), if that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The How

For one-off replace operations, it's good to avoid global conversions to `object` because that's costly processing-wise and memory-wise. But, as @hpaul mentioned in a comment, `None` is an object and not a primitive value, thus a Series *must* be of object type to contain it. e.g. a `datetime` Series will always turn `None` into `NaT`, because that's the primitive representation of the *absence of a primitive date value*. As is `NaN` for numeric dtypes and `category`.

Given that, I found this method to be best:

```py
df.replace((np.nan, ''), (None, None))
```

As a result, we get:

```py
      a                           b     c                   d
0   0.0                        None  None                None
1  10.0  2020-08-14 01:09:41.936421    D1  Long text chunk...
2  20.0  2020-08-14 01:09:41.936421  None  Long text chunk...
3  30.0                        None    D3                None
4  40.0  2020-08-14 01:09:41.936421  None  Long text chunk...
```

Due to also not relying on `.astype` or `.fillna` beforehand, this is both safer (better conversions¹) and more performant than other methods:

```py
In [2]: %timeit -n 1000 df.replace((np.nan, ''), (None, None))
1.32 ms ± 47.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit -n 1000 df.replace({np.nan: None, '': None})
                        # ^ pandas translates this into the first call,
                        # taking a few more milliseconds
1.36 ms ± 38.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit -n 1000 df.astype(object).where(df.notnull(), None).where(df != '', None)
2.83 ms ± 78.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

¹ pandas converts the dtypes it needs to (anything other than numerics and `object` itself) into `object`, but this method is faster because conversion is *lazily* done, and has the advantage of being implicitly handled by pandas. A demonstration:

```py
In [5]: df.dtypes
a           float64
b    datetime64[ns]
c          category
d            object
dtype: object
```

Meanwhile, after the replace

```py
In [6]: df.replace((np.nan, ''), (None, None)).dtypes
a    float64
b     object
c     object
d     object
dtype: object
```

The `float64` column didn't have any empty values to replace, so it didn't change at all.

Do note this is **not** the same as `.replace(np.nan, None).replace('', None)`, which would result in the same `TypeError`, because...

## The Why

The reason this `TypeError` happens goes way back into pandas' Cython implementation of the default replace method, which is called pad or forward fill. But it also has to do with API choices:

- Cython issue: the method called in this scenario (`pandas._libs.algos.pad_inplace`) expects to fill any Series dtype except `category`, that's why the error mentions a *signature* mismatch.
- API uncertainty: Passing `None` as a positional argument can be misleading - pandas treats this as if "you're *not* passing *anything* as the replace value" instead of "you're *passing nothing* as the replace value".

Notice what happens when converting the DataFrame to `object` and then using the same method that once worked:

```py
In [7]: df.astype(object).fillna('').replace('', None)
      a                           b   c                   d
0
1  10.0  2020-08-13 21:18:42.520455  D1  Long text chunk...
2  20.0  2020-08-13 21:18:42.520455  D1  Long text chunk...
3  30.0  2020-08-13 21:18:42.520455  D3  Long text chunk...
4  40.0  2020-08-13 21:18:42.520455  D3  Long text chunk...
```

Values have been *forward filled*, as can be seen more easily in column `c`. This is because, in practice, `.replace('', None)` is the same as `.replace('')`, and pandas' API has taken the route of assuming the above is the kind of behavior sought by this operation - a plain forward fill. Except, as explained, that wouldn't work for `category` dtypes.