# Pandas dataframe replace em-dash with nan

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8

I am trying to read in a large number of .xls and .xlsx files with predominantly numeric data into python using pd.read_excel. However, the files use em-dash for missing values. I am trying to get Python to replace all these em-dashes as nans. I can't seem to find a way to get Python to even recognize the character, let alone replace it. I tried the following which did not work

```
df['var'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(u'\2014','',x))
```

I also tried simply

```
df['var'].astype('float')
```

What would be the best way to get all the em-dashs in a dataframe to convert to nans, while keeping the numeric data as floats?

Comment: Google a bit better mate because I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097236/how-to-replace-values-with-none-in-pandas-data-frame-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) within 10 seconds.

Comment: Duplicate from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097236/how-to-replace-values-with-none-in-pandas-data-frame-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Solution is df.replace()

Comment: The issue is that I have a long dash, not a regular dash. So normal string find/replace functions aren't working. since Python is not matching '-' with '–'. When I keep getting errors like this:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: `pd.read_excel` normally does not use ascii codecs. How exactly do you read the excel files?

Comment: And simply copy-pasting that symbol in the same way? So not a hyphen but the symbol you're looking for?

Answer (score 5):

You should catch the error at an earlier stage. Tell `pd.read_excel()` to treat em-dashes as NaNs:

```
df = pd.read_excel(..., na_values=['–','—'])
```

Comment: Please be specific. How exactly it did not work? Did you get an error message?

Comment: The code ran without an error, but It didn't actually convert the dashes to nans

Comment: Looks like I pasted an en-dash instead of an em-dash in my answer. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most straightforward way to do this would be `pd.to_numeric` with the argument `errors='coerce'`:

```
df['var'] = pd.to_numeric(df['var'], errors='coerce')
```

From the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html):

> If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaN

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what was going on with those dashes (which showed up like u'\u2013' when I would do df.get_value(0,'var')) but I did find a solution that worked, which converted the dashes to nans and kept the numeric data as numbers.

```
import unicodedata

df['var']=df['var'].map(unicode)
df['var']=df['var'].apply(lambda x: unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', x).encode('ascii','ignore'))
df['var']=pd.to_numeric(df['var'])
```

Answer (score -1):

`df.replace({'-': None})` is what you are looking for. Found in another post on stack overflow.